# Check to see if value exists in list - better way than a loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following class data structure:

```
public class clsUser
{
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public List<OrgPermission> orgs { get; set; }
}

public class OrgPermission
{
    public string Org { get; set; }
    public string SubOrg {get;set;}
    public List<string> type { get; set; }
}
```

`List<string> type` can have values such as "admin", "user", "superuser", etc.

so each user can have multiple org-suborg combinations with multiple user roles to each.

orgs and suborgs in the user class can be written out like so: 56% (which means they can see everything that starts with 56)

I want to check if the user has access to org-suborg combination on a page of type "Admin"

right now I am doing it with a loop, which works, like so:

```
foreach (OrgPermission userOrg in user.orgs) {
  if ((ddlOrg.SelectedValue.StartsWith(userOrg.Org.Trim('%'))) && (ddlSubOrg.SelectedValue.StartsWith(userOrg.SubOrg.Trim('%')))) {
    if (userOrg.type.Contains("Admin"))
      btnSubmitToProd.Enabled = true;
    else
      btnSubmitToProd.Enabled = false;
    break; //break out of the loop if the org-sub org match is found
  }
}
```

is there a better way to do this to get rid of the loop maybe? or am I doing it right?

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want:

```
string orgValue = ddlOrg.SelectedValue;
string subOrgValue = ddlSubOrg.SelectedValue;
btnSubmitToProd = user.orgs
                      .Any(org => orgValue.StartsWith(org.Org.Trim('%')) &&
                                  subOrgValue.StartsWith(org.SubOrg.Trim('%')) &&
                                  org.type.Contains("Admin"));
```

Comment: This isn't getting rid of the loop, it just hides it inside "Any(...)", granted it looks way better than original

Comment: @StenPetrov: Sure - but I suspect that's what the OP is actually looking for. Given that there are many things to look through, I can't see how you could expect to ever get rid of looping entirely.

Comment: What OP is doing looks wrong on many levels, so you're most likely right. +1

Comment: @StenPetrov - what's wrong with mine? i'm trying to learn here, please explain

Comment: @MadamZuZu Casing and naming, hardcoded magic string ("Admin") where an enum is likely more appropriate, trimming the Org every time you access it, using `StartsWith` doesn't seem right - probably some pre-parsing into separate fields is a better fit, verbosity of code (consider `buttonSubmit.Enabled = (user.type.Contains("Admin"))`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx):

```
var userIsAdmin = user.orgs.Any(uo => uo.type.Any(uot => uot == "Admin"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about using any inbuild method but i still go by your way , any code will at the end will use the foreach logic only , There is no magic way. Even using for in place of foreach will be much faster. I will still vote the way you are doing because it will give you more power in hand. Using any method like LINQ is fine but for loop is the best one.